# XCode - Testing an application by Building and Running on device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, testflight

I created an iOS application and I have an iPhone 4 to test my application on. Unfortunately, TestFlight can only be downloaded on iOS 8 and the iPhone 4 only supports up to iOS 7.

I wanted to test my in-app purchases. I know when users test in-app purchases using TestFlight, their iTunes account is not charged.

So I was wondering, if I add an email as an internal tester on iTunes Connect but instead of using TestFlight, I just build and run the application on my device through XCode, will I be charged for an in-app purchase?

My intuition says no so if not, is there any other way I can test my in-app purchases without having to buy a new device and let Apple take even more money from me?

Also, are there any other drawbacks to testing by building and running from XCode? Because if there are, I would just go out and buy an iOS 8 device to test properly using TestFlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you test a sandboxed app (eg, not on the app store), you use itunes connect test accounts. These don't have associated credit cards. You don't get charged for this testing.